# Stack array of structures

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list, stack, structure

I'm trying to figure our how implement an array of structures into stacks in this machine problem that i have. Here is the problem:

Make a program that will allow the user to perform the following activities stated below through array approach.  Car Park Station offers 10 park lanes and each lanes can accommodate 5 cars.

a. Entry.  It must be able to register new car and assign an available parking lane.  Registration requires plate number, brand name, car color, owner and telephone number.

b. Release.  It must be able to release car from an identified lane

c. Search.  It must be able to identify the car location based on plate number.

d. Vacancy. It must be able to display available parking space.

From what i understand, i have to make a 2 dimensional array of structures containing various data types and i have to make a lifo code out of it. But my problem is, i know how to simulate an array approach lifo code with just a single data type but not with multiple data types. The part where i have to implement the 2 dimensional array of structure into a stack is where i got me stuck and confused. I've searched online to look for problems similar to mine but i couldn't find any. I tried to make a code shown below:

```
struct Car
{
    string brand, color, owner;
    int plate, phone;
};

class Stack
{
private:
    Car * pointer = new Car[10][5];
    int top;
public:
    Stack() // Constructor
    {...}

    void Push(int plate, string brand, string color, string color, string owner, int number)
    {...}

    Pop()
    {...}

}
```

Comment: `new Car[10][5]`, that's not how  to create a "multi-dimensional" array. Why not simply use an array or arrays? Like `Car* cars[10][5] = {}`? That will define an array of 10 arrays of 5 pointers to `Car`, and initialize all pointers to null.

Comment: And if you want a stack, why not use [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to analyze your problem further before choosing an actual implementation solution (like 2-dim array).

In your task you have the following abstract entities:

- `CarParkStation` with attributes: `NumberOfParkLanes`, which should be able to do something like: `FindFreeLane`, `FindCar(plateNum)`, `RegisterACar(car)`, `ReleaseACar(car)`
- `Lane` with attributes: `NumberOfPlaces`, and with actions like: `IsFull()`, and maybe also: `FindACar(plateNum)`, `AddACar(car)`, `RemoveACar(car)`
- `Car` with attributes: `PlateNumber`, `Brand`, `Color`, `Owner`, which should be able to do: `GetPlateNumber()`, and maybe also provide access to other parameters

Below is a very general example of possible `CarParkStation` class declaration:

```
class CarParkStation
{
public:
    CarParkStation() = delete;
    explicit CarParkStation(int numParkLanes);
    ~CarParkStation() = default;

    std::shared_ptr<const Lane> FindFreeLane();
    std::shared_ptr<const Car> FindCar(const PlateNumber& pNumber);
    std::pair<std::shared_ptr<const Lane>, int position> FindWhereMyCarIsParked(const PlateNumber& pNumber);
    bool RegisterACar(const Car& car);
    bool ReleaseACar(const Car& car);

private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Lane> > lanes_;
    std::set<std::shared_ptr<Car>, CustomCompareFunction > cars_;
};
```

Don't forget to write the tests along with your implementation. This will help you to verify your requirements and overall design. For example:

```
TEST_F(CarParkStationShould, returnCorrectFreeLane)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(expectedFreeLane, carParkStation->FindFreeLane());
}
```

In general, focus on what should your application do first, and then think about how to implement it.